# Xquery processing error (saxon) XPST0003: Left operand of '>' needs parentheses

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

I want to generate an HTML file from XML data using XQuery (with the Saxon XQuery processor).

I am trying to create a list of "intervenants" (teachers), which contains the list of "unites" (classes) each one teaches.

Here is my XQuery code:

```
declare boundary-space preserve;
declare option saxon:output "method=xml";
declare option saxon:output "encoding=iso-8859-1";
declare option saxon:output "doctype-public=-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN";
declare option saxon:output "doctype-system=-http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd";


declare function local:main() {
    let $doc := doc("tp4.xml")/master

    for $intervenant in $doc/intervenants/intervenant
    order by $intervenant/nom
    return local:displayIntervenant($intervenant)
};

declare function local:displayIntervenant($intervenant) {

    <li>{data($intervenant/nom)} {data($intervenant/prénom)}</li>
    <li>Unites: </li>
        <ul>:here will be the function for getting "unites":</ul>

};

<html>
<body>
<h1>Intervenants</h1>
    <ul>
        {local:main()}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following error:

```
$java -cp Saxon/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query !indent=yes xq.txt > www/xq.html
Syntax error on line 19 at column 6 of file:/home/luc/Documents/XML/TP4/xq.txt near {...ant/prénom)}</li> <li>Unite...} 
  XPST0003: Left operand of '>' needs parentheses
```

The line 19 refers to the second `<li>` element.

I don't understand the error message and I can't fix it.

Comment: Not the issue here, but I don't think HTML allows `<ul/>` elements as immediate children of `<ul/>` elements.

Comment: You are right! `<ul/>` can't be immediate children of `<ul/>` elements according to the official dtd of html. Nevertheless, they are correctly interpreted by the most of web browsers. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to return multiple elements in a function. In XQuery, functions are expected to contain a single top-level statement, but multiple elements are multiple statements. Wrap them in a sequence:

```
declare function local:displayIntervenant($intervenant) {
  (   
    <li>{data($intervenant/nom)} {data($intervenant/prénom)}</li>,
    <li>Unites: </li>,
        <ul>:here will be the function for getting "unites":</ul>
  )
};
```

In this case, you can also omit the parenthesis, but have to keep the commas:

```
declare function local:displayIntervenant($intervenant) {
    <li>{data($intervenant/nom)} {data($intervenant/prénom)}</li>,
    <li>Unites: </li>,
        <ul>:here will be the function for getting "unites":</ul>
};
```

If you'd put the `<ul/>` element inside the function (which you currently have in the HTML below the function), you'd also achieve the same goal of having a single top-level statement in the function:

```
declare function local:displayIntervenant($intervenant) {
  <ul>
    <li>{data($intervenant/nom)} {data($intervenant/prénom)}</li>
    <li>Unites: </li>
        <ul>:here will be the function for getting "unites":</ul>
  </ul>
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering the other part of your question, asking for an explanation of the error message.

Producing good error messages in XQuery is difficult because the syntax is quite complicated, and sometimes the parser thinks you were trying to do something completely different from what you thought you were trying to do. What has happened here is that Saxon has parsed the expression:

```
<li>{data($intervenant/nom)} {data($intervenant/prénom)}</li>
```

and then the next thing it sees is "<", which in this context (after an expression) can only be a less-than operator, so it takes that interpretation. It then tries to find the expression on the RHS of the `"<"` operator, and finds "li" (which is a valid expression meaning child::li). So it's read an expression of the form `(A < li)` and the next thing it sees is ">". The only thing this can be is a "greater-than" operator. But a greater-than operator isn't allowed here because the operator precedence is wrong: `(A < li > B)` is not a valid expression. The parser wrongly guesses that what you meant was `(A < li) > B` and expresses the error message in those terms.

This is probably a rather common mistake and I'll see if I can do some special-casing on the diagnostics.

**Later**

I have tweaked the parser so the error message will now be:

XPST0003: Left operand of '>' needs parentheses. Or perhaps an XQuery element constructor appears where it is not allowed